# Using Django HyperlinkedModelSerializer with prefixed view names

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to use HyperlinkedModelSerializer, but I'm getting the error:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "house-detail"

That should be **backend:house-detail**, all views in my REST api have that "backend:" prefix. How can I have Django REST automatically add that prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Still not sure how to do it automatically though, so if I ever change the prefix I need to change things manually.

This is when using base classes and inheritance can help

```
class PrefixedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prefix = 'backend'
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='{}:house-detail'.format(prefix)
    )
```

So now `HouseSerializer` inherits from that base class

```
class HouseSerializer(PrefixedSerializer):
    # the other fields
```

Comment: Great! It seems the Django REST framework doesn;t have a way to do this automatically, but using inheritance is nice here. The "self." does give a variable undefined error though, just removing it makes it work.

Comment: @user1582024 Oh yeah, I didn't really put in effort to give correct syntax, also you may have to isolate the `house-detail` part into a variable in `HouseSerializer` too, but I hope I helped you get the idea how to do this with base classes!

Comment: You certainly did.

Answer (score 0):

To do it manually, do this:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='backend:house-detail'
    )

    ...
```

Still not sure how to do it automatically though, so if I ever change the prefix I need to change things manually.